# Does SOAPUI have the concept of an unexpected message

Tags: soapui

I have a test where I am sending a message in SOAPUI, usually this will trigger an message coming back asynchronously to my Mock Service so I have a Mock Response.

Now I have a testcase where receiving any message to my mock service would be considered failure.

Other tools I have used in the past had the concept of unexpected messages wherein receiving a message would fail the test.

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

Hm..You can add an assertion to Mock Response. There is an assertion inspector at bottom of Mock Response panel. Add script assertion with:

```
assert false
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Let me try that. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I still see my test failing upon not receiving the message. I added a single assertion which is of type script and the only line is assert false.

Comment: Did you try to add an assertion "Not SOAP Fault" ?

Comment: I think these suggestions will not work, because the SOAP step will fail when it does not receive a message, regardless of the asserts.